# Too high positive gross profit margin percentage from negative net sales

Tags: corporate-finance

I don't have a finance background and maybe I 'm missing something. I am given a company dataset which has gross profit margin percentage values for each product. Some values are too high such as 8130.0 % and some values are too low such as -11260.0 %. When I look at the net sales(revenue) and the cost, for the 8130.0 % value for example , the net sales is -400 dollars and the cost is 32300 dollars, as a result, based on the formula, gross profit margin % = 100* (net sales -costs)/net sales, the result is positive and too high. I can see this possible mathematically, but I can't make it sense that negative sales and high costs are creating high gross profit margin, how is this possible? Similarly, for the too low gross profit margin percentage values, net sales are too low but positive and cost are very high resulting too high negative values. I appreciate any input, thanks.